# Filling an array with null when empty

Tags: php, arrays

I couldn't find a similar problem, so I hope you guys can help me.

I'm trying to build a dashboard where there is an overview of the top 10 website positions in Google search over a period of time. Right now we get the data from Goolge and put it in a database, after that we extract the data from the database and manipulate it so it fits in a Highcharts chart.

The problem is that not every site is in the top 10 every time so there wil be holes in the data.

An array should look something like this in the end `[9,7,8,0,0,10]` for a date range like this `["2016-05-15", "2016-05-16", "2016-05-17", "2016-05-18", "2016-05-19", "2016-05-20"]` (a zero is for everytime a site is not in the top 10). But the result we get right now is like this `[9,7,8,10]` (so it pushes all the values to the front of the array). I tried to calculate the amount of days between everytime the site is in the top 10, but this gives me an array like `[9,9,9,9,8,9]`

This is the code I have so far

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$matchFound = false;

for($i = 0; $i < count($urlData); $i++) {

    if($urlData[$i]["keyword"] == $row["keyword"]){
        addDates($row["date"]);
        if(!isset($prevDate)){
            $urlData[$i]["urlpos"][$row["url"]][] = $row["position"];
            $prevDate = $row["date"];
        }else {
            if(calcDateDiff($prevDate, $row["date"]) > 1){
                for($i = 0; $i < calcDateDiff($prevDate, $row["date"]); $i++){
                    $urlData[$i]["urlpos"][$row["url"]][] = 0;
                }
                $urlData[$i]["urlpos"][$row["url"]][] = $row["position"];
                $prevDate = $row["date"];
            }else {
                $urlData[$i]["urlpos"][$row["url"]][] = $row["position"];
                $prevDate = $row["date"];
            }
        }

        $matchFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$matchFound) {
    $urlData[] = array(
        "keyword" => $row["keyword"],
        "urlpos" => array(
            $row["url"] => array($row["position"])
        )
    );

}
}


function calcDateDiff($firstAppearence, $seconAppearance){
    $first = strtotime($firstAppearence);
    $second  = strtotime($seconAppearance);

    $days = floor(($second - $first) / (60*60*24));
    return $days;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May the for of calcDateDiff not be triggerring correctly, have you debugged the formats of dates?

Answer (score 0):

Use keys in your array like:

```
'fishes.com' => position [0=> 10, 1 => 0, 2=> ...]
```

---

Anyway, this code works fine:

```
$a = [9,7,8,0,0,10];
var_dump ($a);
```

So maybe you are not handling and assigning correctly.
So why don't you try to change the schema more like a DB, kind of, an array of dates, that contains the 10 top sites. 
Other array, mapping the site id with the name. Or just site name directly if youu feel that could be uniquely retrieved. It would seem easier approach for me.